# How to read to a file path or folder name with a defined string but variable suffix python

Tags: python

I have some folder paths that hold model information:

```
C:\Users\Latitude User\OneDrive\Projects\xxxx\xxxx\xxxx\Predictions\V1_1234

C:\Users\Latitude User\OneDrive\Projects\xxxx\xxxx\xxxx\Predictions\V2_4567

C:\Users\Latitude User\OneDrive\Projects\xxxx\xxxx\xxxx\Predictions\V3_789
```

The numbers on the end of the folder are actually MAE numbers of the model, so they will change from time to time. But the V1, V2, V3 wont which is why I would like to hard code them below.

I want to call in those folders but ignore the `_1234` at the end. I tried adding a * but it also threw an error:

```
path = r'C:\Users\Latitude User\OneDrive\Projects\xxxx\xxxx\xxxx\Predictions\\'

model1= 'V1'
model2= 'V2'


deploy1 = run_my_model('Model.csv', path + model1 + '*\\')
deploy2 = run_my_model('Model.csv', path + model2 + '*\\')
```

> OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument:

Any ideas on how I could program to call the defined name, ignoring the numbers afterwards? Thanks!

Comment: Use `glob` library in python

Comment: thanks @bigbounty. how exactly would I do that?

Comment: You can't really 'ignore' a part of path. Does the number depend on the model? Or is it always the highest number of the current `V*`? Then you could check for it or set it together with the `V*` string.

Comment: Im basically printing the current MAE score of the model (eg_134) to make it easier to compare. So the number will change at differnt times. There will never be two of the same folder prefixes though as they are models with different settings (V1,V2,V3 etc)

Comment: The function `run_my_model()` is throwing the exception. But you are not showing us *the code in that function*. So you are asking us to imagine what to have written and suggest how to fix it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try using glob? Glob allows wildcards in the file/folder paths. May be it will be helpful. The code snippet

```
import glob
for name in glob.glob('V1*/Model.csv'):
    print(name)
for name in glob.glob('V2*/Model.csv'):
    print(name)
```

gives following output if you have folders V1_1234 and V2_4567:

```
V1_1234/Model.csv
V2_4567/Model.csv
```

Comment: Great! FYI i ended up defining `model1= glob.glob(path + 'V1*)` which gave me the string to the full folder name. thanks!!

Comment: glad I could help. :)